# Should i pull the plug?

Tags: hdmi

I just connected my raspberry-pi to a screen that isn't outputting anything , but i know the pi is working due to the red light being on, and now i want to connect it to a working device but I've heard that cutting power without properly shutting down can damage the raspberry pi. I'm new to raspberry pi and don't know what to do, any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: It's probably ok to pull the plug while the green ACT light is not blinking/hasn't blinked for a while, cause it usually indicates disk activity.

Comment: `cutting power without properly shutting down can damage the raspberry pi` not really - you may cause corruption of the filesystem - but that isn't strictly "damage"

Answer (score 1):

> i know the pi is working due to the red light being on

If that's all that's on then it is not booting, so yes you can pull the plug.  There is a green led (ACT) next to the red led (PWR), "ACT" I believe referring to that by default it indicates activity on the SD card reader.  If that never happens, then the SD card is not formatted properly or the Pi is broken/defective.  Normally it should flicker irregularly for at least 15-20 seconds before going mostly dark.  If instead it blinks in a regular pattern continuously, there is a more subtle problem with the SD card and you should consult the documentation for the meaning of the specific blinking pattern.